# PointCloud to LaserScan Kinect

Tags: navigation, kinect, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the slam_gmapping, and I have created this launch file, that is mentioned here http://answers.ros.org/question/10606/problem-launching-pointcloud-to-laserscan/, but when I try to run it... this error comes:

```
[ INFO] [1374529520.364476474]: Initializing nodelet with 8 worker threads.
process[kinect_laser-25]: started with pid [23477]
[ERROR] [1374529520.386493921]: Failed to load nodelet [/pointcloud_throttle] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_topic_tools/NodeletThrottleString nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader pcl/BoundaryEstimation pcl/ConvexHull2D pcl/EuclideanClusterExtraction pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/ExtractPolygonalPrismData pcl/FPFHEstimation pcl/FPFHEstimationOMP pcl/MomentInvariantsEstimation pcl/MovingLeastSquares pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/NormalEstimation pcl/NormalEstimationOMP pcl/NormalEstimationTBB pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PFHEstimation pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/PrincipalCurvaturesEstimation pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/SACSegmentation pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals pcl/SegmentDifferences pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/TestListener pcl/TestPingPong pcl/TestTalker pcl/VFHEstimation pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2 test_nodelet/ConsoleTest test_nodelet/Plus
[FATAL] [1374529520.386692115]: Service call failed!
[ERROR] [1374529520.400198187]: Failed to load nodelet [/kinect_laser] of type [pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan]: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan with base class type nodelet::Nodelet does not exist. Declared types are  depth_image_proc/convert_metric depth_image_proc/disparity depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb depth_image_proc/register image_proc/crop_decimate image_proc/debayer image_proc/rectify image_view/disparity image_view/image nodelet_topic_tools/NodeletThrottleString nodelet_tutorial_math/Plus openni_camera/driver pcl/BAGReader pcl/BoundaryEstimation pcl/ConvexHull2D pcl/EuclideanClusterExtraction pcl/ExtractIndices pcl/ExtractPolygonalPrismData pcl/FPFHEstimation pcl/FPFHEstimationOMP pcl/MomentInvariantsEstimation pcl/MovingLeastSquares pcl/NodeletDEMUX pcl/NodeletMUX pcl/NormalEstimation pcl/NormalEstimationOMP pcl/NormalEstimationTBB pcl/PCDReader pcl/PCDWriter pcl/PFHEstimation pcl/PassThrough pcl/PointCloudConcatenateDataSynchronizer pcl/PointCloudConcatenateFieldsSynchronizer pcl/PrincipalCurvaturesEstimation pcl/ProjectInliers pcl/SACSegmentation pcl/SACSegmentationFromNormals pcl/SegmentDifferences pcl/StatisticalOutlierRemoval pcl/TestListener pcl/TestPingPong pcl/TestTalker pcl/VFHEstimation pcl/VoxelGrid stereo_image_proc/disparity stereo_image_proc/point_cloud stereo_image_proc/point_cloud2 test_nodelet/ConsoleTest test_nodelet/Plus
[FATAL] [1374529520.400328595]: Service call failed!
[pointcloud_throttle-24] process has died [pid 23434, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager cloud_in:=/camera/depth/points cloud_out:=cloud_throttled __name:=pointcloud_throttle __log:=/root/.ros/log/0096b582-f318-11e2-85b3-001d7e0aced1/pointcloud_throttle-24.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/0096b582-f318-11e2-85b3-001d7e0aced1/pointcloud_throttle-24*.log
[kinect_laser-25] process has died [pid 23477, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager cloud:=cloud_throttled __name:=kinect_laser __log:=/root/.ros/log/0096b582-f318-11e2-85b3-001d7e0aced1/kinect_laser-25.log].
log file: /root/.ros/log/0096b582-f318-11e2-85b3-001d7e0aced1/kinect_laser-25*.log
[ERROR] [1374529520.973861837]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1374529520.987485340]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1374529521.000773838]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
[ INFO] [1374529521.770846682]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1374529521.771127177]: 1. device on bus 002:10 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00366902423046A'
[ INFO] [1374529521.772878160]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1374529521.823429316]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 2:10 with serial number 'A00366902423046A'
[ INFO] [1374529521.871688164]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1374529521.871813748]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame' 
[ WARN] [1374529521.880133599]: Camera calibration file /root/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00366902423046A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1374529521.880240850]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1374529521.880421612]: Camera calibration file /root/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00366902423046A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1374529521.880527179]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

How can I make it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68143/pointcloud-to-laserscan-kinect/) by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have met the same error; and then i find that i haven't install pointcloud_to_laserscan, after install, it success.you can try...

---

Originally posted by [jiemao0125](https://answers.ros.org/users/5512/jiemao0125/) with karma: 31 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-07-23**:
thanks for the reply, could u tell me how can I install it?

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-07-23**:
You probably just install the package. Use "apt-cache search ros-fuerte" to find the name of the package you need to install. It will probably look like "ros-fuerte-pointcloud-to-laserscan"

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-07-24**:
I installed the ros-fuerte-perception-pcl and ros-fuerte-pcl which are the ones most likely similar in name to point cloud, but I keep getting the same result....

**Comment by [Hemu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4541/hemu/) on 2013-07-24**:
The pointcloud_to_laserscan is in the turtlebot stack. So, install the turtlebot stack using sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-turtlebot.

**Comment by [jiemao0125](https://answers.ros.org/users/5512/jiemao0125/) on 2013-07-24**:
I do like this;    see http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan; and

1. hg clone http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan;
2. roscd pointcloud_to_laserscan; rosmake;
   then can work;
   hope that help you